# Consigo utilizar o NHibernate com docker?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Tenho um projeto pessoal em ASP.NET MVC core que suporta Docker. Gostaria de usar o NHibernate para persistir e recuperar informações. Em minhas buscas não encontrei ninguém que utiliza. Estou tentando mas ocorre o seguinte erro:

Exceção interna:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Chamo o método que atualiza ou gera as tabelas do banco na classe program.cs

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Chamando o método que Gera ou atualiza as tabelas do banco de dados
    NHibernateHelper.GerarOuAtualizarTabelas();
    // Iniciando o Host Web
   CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

A classe `NHibernateHelper`:

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory fabrica = CriaSessionFactory();

    private static ISessionFactory CriaSessionFactory()
    {
        Configuration cfg = RecuperaConfiguracao();
        return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Configuration RecuperaConfiguracao()
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        return cfg;
    }

    public static void GerarOuAtualizarTabelas()
    {
        Configuration config = RecuperaConfiguracao();
        new SchemaExport(config).Create(true, true);
    }

    public static ISession AbreSession()
    {

        return fabrica.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Ao alternar para rodar com 'IIS Express', funciona normalmente, já tentei configurar o `docker` com ajuda de alguns páginas para permitir conexões remotas, mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Mostra um trecho do código em que o erro é gerado.

Comment: Anexei como resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Henrique,

não há nenhum problema com o NHibernate que o impeça de rodar com Windows Containers ou com Linux Containers, ultimamente tenho rodado muito com docker no linux.

Teu cenário é no windows, no entanto o erro que você está informando não é um erro no NHibernate, essa é a mensagem default de falta de conectividade no ADO.NET com o SQL Server.

Acredito que teu problema seja a connectionstring.

Imagino que não tenha entendido bem como a parte de network no docker funciona e esteja usando um endereço de loopback como localhost ou 127.0.0.1 para conectar nesse banco ou esteja usando outro IP errado.

De qualquer forma teu problema não é no NHibernate, essa não é uma exception dele, o stack trace vai te assegurar a respeito do que estou dizendo.

Revisite as aulas sobre docker networking e entenda a melhor forma de montar tua connectionstring. Temos grupos de apoio no telegram.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!